# Alamofireでの処理について

Tags: swift, swift2

Alamofire自体が非同期通信というのは存じております。
Alamofireを利用してデータをPOSTしたいと考えているのですが、
「A」「B」「C」という3つの処理があり、

> ①「A」が正常に終わると「B」に移行する
>   ②「B」を正常に処理し終えると「C」に移行する。
>   ③「B」で受け取ったデータを元にデータを処理し、「C」の処理で送信し処理を終える。

要するに「A」が終わってから「B」
「B」が終わってから「C」の順番で処理を行うことは可能でしょうか。

「A」「B」「C」それぞれがAlamofireでの処理になります。

> 例）「A」-> アカウント登録
>   　　「B」-> ログイン要求
>   　　「C」-> ログイン処理のためのハッシュ送信

一つずつキューを使って処理すべきなのでしょうか。

Comment: 直列なキューの非同期処理？というやつでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

非同期処理をうまく使いこなすコツは「待たない」こと、完了後のデータが必要な処理は完了ハンドラの中に書くことの2点です。

ただ、コメントに示したように「普通に入れ子にする」と、どうひいき目に見ても見やすいとは思えないコードになってしまいます。

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlA, headers: headersA, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            //...Aのレスポンスに対する処理
            let urlB = ...
            let headersB: [String: String] = ...
            Alamofire.request(.POST, urlB, headers: headersB, encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    //...Bのレスポンスに対する処理
                    let urlC = ...
                    let headersC: [String: String] = ...
                    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlC, headers: headersC, encoding: .JSON)
                        .responseJSON { response in
                            //...Cのレスポンスに対する処理
                    }
            }
    }
```

こういう場合、完了ハンドラをクロージャーとして直接書かずに、メソッドで指定すれば少し見やすくなるのではないかと思います。

完了ハンドラ群をこんな感じでメソッドで定義しておきます。

```
private func onResponseA(response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) {
    //...Aのレスポンスに対する処理
    let urlB = ...
    let headersB: [String: String] = ...
    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlB, headers: headersB, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: onResponseB)
}
private func onResponseB(response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) {
    //...Bのレスポンスに対する処理
    let urlC = ...
    let headersC: [String: String] = ...
    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlC, headers: headersC, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: onResponseC)
}
private func onResponseC(response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) {
    //...Cのレスポンスに対する処理
}
```

後は、最初の完了ハンドラを指定して、最初のリクエストを投げるだけです。

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlA, headers: headersA, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: onResponseA)
```

入れ子にするパターンも、完了ハンドラを別メソッドにするパターンも、要は「前の処理の完了ハンドラの中で、次のリクエストを送信する」ということを続けているだけです。

上のどちらかのやり方で確実に処理ができるはずです。Appleのサンプルコードを見回しても、非同期処理の終了を待ち合わせるために`NSRunLoop`を使うようなコードは全くありません。是非ともそんな「脆い」方法をとらず、確実に動作する方法をとられるよう強くお勧めしておきます。

Comment: 完了ハンドラ郡をメソッドで定義しておく方法で無事処理できました。NSRunLoopを使用する方法は確実ではないのですね。大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

[参考サイト](http://qiita.com/kazuhirox/items/9ecb25bc238ad2d47ff0)

↑ こちらのサイトのやり方で無事処理させることが出来ました。

```
//ロックの取得
var keepAlive = true

Alamofire.request(.POST, url, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { response in
        ・・・データを受信した際の処理・・・
        //ロックの解除
        keepAlive = false
}

//ロックが解除されるまで待つ
let runLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
while keepAlive &&
    runLoop.runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1)) {
    // 0.1秒毎の処理なので、処理が止まらない
}

・・・後続の処理・・・
```

Comment: そのやり方はあまりお勧めできるものではありません。と言うのは、通常のViewController内のメソッドはNSRunLoopに管理されて実行されており、「NSRunLoopで管理されているメソッドの中からまたNSRunLoopを回す」といった処理をすると、(そんなことはApple的には想定していないので)動作は未定義、微妙なタイミングで起動されるべきメソッドが実行されるかどうかは運任せ、と言う状態になってしまいます。Apple製フレームワークにはpromiseだのasync/awaitだのが無いのであまりかっこよくは書けないのですが、「普通に入れ子にする」ことで処理可能なはずです。